# rails polymorphic association reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a polymorphic association as follows

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :file
end
```

Then on my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable
```

The I want to be able to do the following

```
attachment = Attachment.create(:file => params[:attachment])
attachment.user = current_user
```

But I am getting a

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `user=' for #<Attachment:0x007fee92901ce8>
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? The one you have given is not specific enough.

Comment: *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `user=' for #<Attachment:0x007fee92901ce8>

Comment: polymorphic associations can be inversed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `attachment` belongs to a `attachable` (which is polymorphic). The proper way to set this is to do so:

```
attachment.attachable = current_user
```

---

I strongly **recommend you to rename your relationship** to the following:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :owner
```

Because the relationship's name `owner` is way more explicit than `attachable`. See for yourself:

```
# What is easier to understan?
attachment.attachable = current_user
# or 
attachment.owner = current_user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a polymorphic relation that way. It'd have to be

`attachment.attachable = current_user`